# Loading file from .apk into application without context

Tags: java, android, apk

I instrument an .apk file and add two files: A "message.txt" file which contains the string "Hello World!" and a MessageLoader.java class file which looks like this:

```
public class MessageLoader {
    public static String getMessage() {
        // load message.txt here
    }
}
```

I can modify the `MessageLoader` and can choose where to put the text file (like in assets/ or res/raw/). The `MessageLoader.getMessage()` method will be called by the app but I don't get a `Context`.

Is there any way without a `Context` to load the "message.txt" file and it's contents in the `getMessage()` method?

I already saw solutions which add an Activity which provides it's `Context` in a static field / with a static method but can't use this solution in this case.

Update: This is not about getting a `Context`. It's all about loading a file from the apk without a context. If there is no solution, because Android only allows it with a context, then I already have a solution using a context. But it's kinda messy...

Comment: Why don't you use a `static` reference to your `Application` instance (**not** an `Activity`)? That won't cause memory leaks and you'd always have a valid context.

Comment: I have no access to the code of the app. I can only change the code of the `MessageLoader` class, which I add to the apk.